# Java Application game shows blank page and then loads after the game is complete

Tags: java

In my application, I called a MathIsBomb game from another package. I got the game from github and it works perfectly fine when I run the MathIsBomb.java file. However, when I click a button to call it, it only shows a blank page. Then, when the game ends (after losing 3 lives), suddenly you can see all the background and stuff.

Button that calls it:

```
    private void MathIsBombButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        MathIsBomb kbm = new MathIsBomb();
    }
```

MathIsBomb.java:

```
public class MathIsBomb {
    Bombs bs = new Bombs();
    InputLogic il = new InputLogic();
    ControllKeys ck = new ControllKeys();
    
    int width = 1280;
    int height=720;
    
    int score = 0;
    int lives=3;
    int counter =0;
    int sleep = 3;
    int module = 400;
    
    JLabel scoreL = new JLabel();
    JLabel livesL = new JLabel();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    List<Bomb> bArray= new ArrayList<Bomb>(4);
    
    public MathIsBomb() {
        String[] options = new String[] {"Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "All of them", "Exit"};
        int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Type the answer and hit enter before the bomb touches the ground!", "MathIsBomb",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
        System.out.println(response);
        
        Gui g= new Gui(width,height,f);
        
        f.addKeyListener(ck);
        
        scoreL.setText("Score: "+score);
        scoreL.setForeground(Color.white);
        scoreL.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        scoreL.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
        
        livesL.setText("Lives: "+lives);
        livesL.setForeground(Color.red);
        livesL.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        livesL.setBounds(10,50,200,40);
        
        g.add(scoreL);
        g.add(livesL);
        
        while(true) {
            if(counter%module==0) {
                switch(response) {
                    case 0:bArray.add(bs.newPlusBomb(width)); break;
                    case 1:bArray.add(bs.newMinusBomb(width)); break;
                    case 2:bArray.add(bs.newMultiplyBomb(width)); break;
                    case 3:bArray.add(bs.newAllBomb(width)); break;
                    case 4: f.dispose();
                }
                g.add(bArray.get(bArray.size()-1));
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        for(int i=0;i<bArray.size();i++) {
            bArray.get(i).move(1);
            if(bArray.get(0).getY()>height-200) {
                ck.initArray();
                lives--;
                livesL.setText("Lives: "+lives);
                bArray.get(0).endofTime();
                bArray.get(0).setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                bArray.get(0).setForeground(Color.red);
                bArray.get(0).setText(""+bArray.get(0).output());
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bArray.get(0).setVisible(false);
                bArray.remove(0);
                
                if(lives==0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Game Over.\nYour score is : "+score+" points."); 
                    response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?", "Math is BOMB",
                            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
                            
                    System.out.println(response);
                    for(int k=0;k<bArray.size();k++) {
                        bArray.get(k).setVisible(false);
                        g.remove(bArray.get(k));
                    }
                    bArray.clear();
                    lives=3;
                    score=0;
                    scoreL.setText("Score: "+score);
                    livesL.setText("Lives: "+lives);
                    counter =0;
                    sleep = 4;
                    module = 300;
                    break;              
                }
            }
            
            if(il.correctInput(ck.getArray(), bArray.get(0).output())) {
                ck.initArray();
                score++;
                scoreL.setText("Score: "+score);
                bArray.get(0).endofTime();
                bArray.get(0).setText(""+bArray.get(0).output());
                bArray.get(0).setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bArray.get(0).setVisible(false);
                bArray.remove(0);
            }
            
            if(score>=10 && score<20) {
                sleep=3;
                module=275;
            }
            else if(score>=20) {
                sleep=2;
                module=225;
            }
        }       
            counter++;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MathIsBomb();
    }
}
```

How do I make all of it display correctly? Did I call the class incorrectly?

Comment: Where did you define the following classes: `Bombs`, `Bomb`, `InputLogic`, `ControlKeys`? I can't run your example without them.

Comment: I defined those classes in a separate package titled ```games.MathIsBomb```. The button that was used to call it is in ```games``` package. If you need the github link, https://github.com/LirakR/Math-is-bomb_Educative-Java-Game